# How does the least squares solution replace expectation by averages over the training data?

Tags: regression, least-squares, statsmodels

This is a follow-up question for [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/455860/underlying-similarities-between-knn-and-least-squares)

This question is related to what is written in 19 page of ESL.

We have two statements. The following is a quote from the post.

> The one below is the matrix notation of the Least squares equation,
> after derivating w.r.t .  **(eq: 2.6)**
>
> $\widehat{\beta} = (\mathbf{X}^{T}\mathbf{X})^{-1}\mathbf{X}\boldsymbol{y}$
>
> The second equation is obtained after assuming $f(x)\approx x^{T}\beta$.  This is then substituted in the equation EPE()=E(−())2
> and then differentiating, we get the below equation **(eq: 2.16)**
>
> $\beta =(E[X^{T}X])^{-1}E[XY]$

Regarding the two statements, the books says

> The least squares solution (2.6) amounts to replacing the expectation
> in (2.16) by averages over the training data.

I am not clear abou what it means by saying replacing the expectation by averages over the training data. Where does the averages come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite that formula for $\hat\beta$ as
$$\hat\beta = \left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_ix_i^T\right)^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^Ty_i \right)$$
which is the formula for $\beta$ only with the expectations replaced by averages over the $n$ observations in the sample.